# NuGet hash validation failed NU1403

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have a solution and it working on other developer's laptops, but on one by some reason during build, I see the next error:

> Error NU1403  Package content hash validation failed for
> Lucene.Net.Contrib.3.0.3. The package is different than the last
> restore.

build is failed by this reason.

at packeges folder I see correct Lucene.Net.Contrib.3.0.3 , what could be a reson for it and how to fix ?

Comment: Probably the source of the package is different and not lock the NuGet source with NuGet.Config is causing the issue. You can refer to this link(https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7921#issuecomment-478152479) if it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clean up the global packaged folder fixed this issue.
path is %userprofile%.nuget\packages